# How to return Java Object from Retrofit2 call OnResponse

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2, response

I have a Restful API whos return a Java Object for me. When return that object it is still empty, because the async thread is still working. How can get that response and return then to my Presenter and it directs the correct response to the view?

That is my retrofit call:

```
 public String checkUser(final ModelUser modelUser) throws IOException {

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(UserRetrofitAPI.BASE_SERVICE)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    UserRetrofitAPI userRetrofitAPI = retrofit.create(UserRetrofitAPI.class);
    Call<ModelUser> requestCheckUser = userRetrofitAPI.checkUser(modelUser.getUser(), modelUser.getPassword());
    requestCheckUser.enqueue(new Callback<ModelUser>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ModelUser> call, retrofit2.Response<ModelUser> response) {
            if(!response.isSuccessful()){

                myModelUser = new ModelUser(modelUser.getUser(),modelUser.getPassword(), String.valueOf(response.code()));

            } else {

                ModelUser modelUserChecked = response.body();
                myModelUser = modelUserChecked;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ModelUser> call, Throwable t) {

            Exception ex = new Exception(t);

            myModelUser = new ModelUser(modelUser.getUser(), modelUser.getPassword(), ex.toString());

        }
    });

    return myModelUser.getResponse();
}
```

when I do this debugging, it works, by processing time.

help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You shouldn't return that directly.

As you mentioned Retrofit response is updated in background thread.

I would suggest to return `requestCheckUser` only and observe that in your **Presenter**

```
public Call<ModelUser> checkUser(final ModelUser modelUser) throws IOException {

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(UserRetrofitAPI.BASE_SERVICE)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    UserRetrofitAPI userRetrofitAPI = retrofit.create(UserRetrofitAPI.class);
    Call<ModelUser> requestCheckUser = userRetrofitAPI.checkUser(modelUser.getUser(), modelUser.getPassword());

    return requestCheckUser;
}
```

**Observe** response of that call in **Presenter** and perform required operations as follows

```
checkUser(modelUser).enqueue(new Callback<ModelUser>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ModelUser> call, retrofit2.Response<ModelUser> response) {
        if(!response.isSuccessful()){

            myModelUser = new ModelUser(modelUser.getUser(),modelUser.getPassword(), String.valueOf(response.code()));

        } else {

            ModelUser modelUserChecked = response.body();
            myModelUser = modelUserChecked;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ModelUser> call, Throwable t) {

        Exception ex = new Exception(t);

        myModelUser = new ModelUser(modelUser.getUser(), modelUser.getPassword(), ex.toString());

    }
});
```

This would be the **simple option** and will **satisfy** this use case and scope.
You can use **custom Interface Listeners** if you don't prefer to write observer in Presenter.

I would recommend to look into **RxJava and use it with Retrofit** to convert this into more maintainable code